# How to remove unnecessary characters from a SQL*Plus result?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm looking for a way of removing all unnecessary characters from a SQL*Plus query result.

**FYI: my company requires to hide any data before I post questions here, so I've replaced ALL column names with XXXXXXX (the lenght of the words stays the same) and all data with DDDDDDDD. I'm sorry for doing this but I don't want any trouble ;)**

FIRSTLY: I want to reduce all the SQL*Plus output to one of two examples.

The first one is the same as a result of a query in PL/SQL Developer, and it looks like this:

```
DDDD,DDDD,DDDDDD,DDDDDDDDD,,,DDDDDDDDDDDD,DDDDDDD,DDDDDDDDD,D,DDDDDDDDD,DDDDDDDDD, ,DDD,DDD,DDD,D
DDDD,DDDD,DDDDDD,DDDDDDDDD,,,DDDDDDDDDDDD,DDDDDDD,DDDDDDDDD,D,DDDDDDDDD,DDDDDDDDD, ,DDD,DDD,DDD,D
DDDD,DDDD,DDDDDD,DDDDDDDDD,,,DDDDDDDDDDDD,DDDDDDD,DDDDDDDDD,D,DDDDDDDDD,DDDDDDDDD, ,DDD,DDD,DDD,D
```

The second possibility (with the column names, as default in SQLPlus:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXX,        XXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXX,X,XXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXX,  X,XXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
------------------,------------------,------------------------,----------------------,-----------,---------,------------,-------------------,---------,-,---------,---------,---,------------,----------------,----------------,----------------
              DDDD,              DDDD,          DDDDDD,         DDDDDDDDD,           ,         ,DDDDDDDDDDDD,        DDDDDDD,DDDDDDDDD,D,DDDDDDDDD,DDDDDDDDD,DDD,         DDD,             DDD,             DDD,               D
```

You have the basics. Now. For the current results I have.

Pure SQLPlus result with only one modification which is

```
set colsep ','
```

Looks like this:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
------------------,------------------                                           
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                        
--------------------------------------------------                              
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------                              
XXXXXXXXX                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XXXX
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                               ,XXXXXXXXX,X,XXXXXXXXX        
--------------------------------------------------,---------,-,---------        
XXXXXXXXX,X,XXXXXXXXXXXX                                      ,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
---------,-,--------------------------------------------------,---------------- 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                               
----------------,----------------                                               
              DDDD,              DDDD
```

As You can see, there are tons of --------- there, and the piece of the result I've shown You is covering JUST the results from first 2 columns (DDDD,DDDD). There is no need to paste all the results, but they look the same. The mix of column names and ---------- is repeating many times, just to cover one or two results. This makes all the result totally unreadable.

I've tried to do the same with this set of commands:

```
set heading off
set recsep off
```

The result I got was CLOSE to what I wanted... but still FULL of unnecessary spaces and line breaks (I assume that the line breaks are coming from the

```
linesize
```

property.

It looks like this:

```
DDDDDDD, DDDDDDD
DDDDDDD                                           ,DDDDDDDDD,D,DDDDDDDDD
DDDDDDDDD, ,DD                                                ,             DDD
         DDD,               D
```

Is there any way of removing all the unneccessary spaces and linebreaks?

**What would be the best method to write ONE styling for the SQLPlus output that will produce at least readable results for different set of queries?**

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way -> Just concatenate your output ( gives you the benefit of easily formating your dates and numbers on the fly)

```
select          yourCharColumn1
        ||';'|| yourCharColumn2
        ||';'|| to_char( yourDateColumn1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
        ||';'|| trim( yourCharColumn3 ) --trim if necessary
 from yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

`SQL*Plus` provides many `formatting options`. You could chose to use them accordingly.

```
SET LINESIZE 1000
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET TRIMOUT ON
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET COLSEP |
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET SPACE 0
```

Let's see a demo.

Raw output, without any formatting.

```
SQL> select * from emp;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800
        20

      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300
        30

      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500
        30


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975
        20

      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1250       1400
        30

      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2850
        30


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450
        10

      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000
        20

      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5000
        10


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1500          0
        30

      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1100
        20

      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        950
        30


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3000
        20

      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1300
        10


14 rows selected.
```

Let's format and see.

```
SQL> SET LINESIZE 16000
SQL> SET ECHO OFF
SQL> SET FEEDBACK OFF
SQL> SET VERIFY OFF
SQL> SET HEADING OFF
SQL> SET TERMOUT OFF
SQL> SET TRIMOUT ON
SQL> SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SQL> SET COLSEP |
SQL> SET NEWPAGE NONE
SQL> SET PAGESIZE 0
SQL> SET SPACE 0
SQL>
SQL> select * from emp;
      7369|SMITH     |CLERK    |      7902|17-DEC-80|       800|          |        20
      7499|ALLEN     |SALESMAN |      7698|20-FEB-81|      1600|       300|        30
      7521|WARD      |SALESMAN |      7698|22-FEB-81|      1250|       500|        30
      7566|JONES     |MANAGER  |      7839|02-APR-81|      2975|          |        20
      7654|MARTIN    |SALESMAN |      7698|28-SEP-81|      1250|      1400|        30
      7698|BLAKE     |MANAGER  |      7839|01-MAY-81|      2850|          |        30
      7782|CLARK     |MANAGER  |      7839|09-JUN-81|      2450|          |        10
      7788|SCOTT     |ANALYST  |      7566|19-APR-87|      3000|          |        20
      7839|KING      |PRESIDENT|          |17-NOV-81|      5000|          |        10
      7844|TURNER    |SALESMAN |      7698|08-SEP-81|      1500|         0|        30
      7876|ADAMS     |CLERK    |      7788|23-MAY-87|      1100|          |        20
      7900|JAMES     |CLERK    |      7698|03-DEC-81|       950|          |        30
      7902|FORD      |ANALYST  |      7566|03-DEC-81|      3000|          |        20
      7934|MILLER    |CLERK    |      7782|23-JAN-82|      1300|          |        10
SQL>
```